# Opening Mobile Device's Image gallery in Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript, air, adobe, flash-builder

i am developing an Adobe AIR Mobile Application with Flashbuilder and Actionscript. I need to open the device's (mobile phone or tab) image gallery on a button click event and select the image to load in my AIR Application. Could anyone please help me in that... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [CameraRoll API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html).  Note that this only returns photos (and not video).  Someone ask this same question on the Adobe forums, [check it out](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3678561).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, that helps a lot. I am able to open image gallery now, what i have to do is, Select the image from gallery and load in Image control in my app